# Attaching formatted cells to lotus notes email

Tags: excel, vba, email, lotus-notes, richtext

I have written the below code. It has worked for sending simple emails.

Now I want the email body with the range of cells added formatted (color and borders).

I did my best to study the answers that were there before, and adjust the code.

I want that the range will appear in the email body with it's formats?

```vb
Sub SendEmail()

Dim TodayDate As Date
Dim x As Integer, A As Integer
Dim UserName As String
Dim MailDbName As String, msgboxtitle As String
Dim Recipient As Variant
Dim Maildb As Object
Dim MailDoc As Object
Dim AttachME As Object
Dim Session As Object
Dim stSignature As String
Dim Sent As String, EmailTo As String
Dim RecipientEmail As String, Subject As String
Dim rng As range

RecipientEmail = Worksheets("Email").range("B1").Value
EmailTo = Worksheets("Email").range("C3").Value
Subject = Worksheets("Email").range("B2").Value
Set rng = Worksheets("Email").range("B3:C10")

' Open and locate current LOTUS NOTES User
Set Session = CreateObject("Notes.NotesSession")
UserName = Session.UserName
MailDbName = Left$(UserName, 1) & Right$(UserName, (Len(UserName) - InStr(1, UserName, " "))) & ".nsf"
Set Maildb = Session.GetDatabase("", MailDbName)

If Maildb.IsOpen = True Then
Else
    Maildb.OPENMAIL
End If
    
' Create New Mail and Address Title Handlers
Set MailDoc = Maildb.CREATEDOCUMENT
MailDoc.Form = "Memo"

' Select range of e-mail addresses

MailDoc.SendTo = RecipientEmail
MailDoc.Subject = Subject
MailDoc.body = rng
MailDoc.SaveMessageOnSend = True
MailDoc.PostedDate = Now()
On Error GoTo errorhandler1
MailDoc.Send 0, RecipientEmail
Set Maildb = Nothing
Set MailDoc = Nothing
Set Session = Nothing
            
errorhandler1:
    Set Maildb = Nothing
    Set MailDoc = Nothing
    Set Session = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

As Richard have rightly mentioned, you are pulling the formatted cell ranges from excel and trying to put it in richtext. It won't work as is.

Either you have to (1)use third part libraries or you have (2) manually pull data from each cell and create NotesRichTextTable item to add values or (3) convert your email doc to mime parts(html), attach the excel formatted content and send the mime doc as email.

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to do this.

You are going to have to pull the DisplayFormat information out of the Excel cells and use it to manually create a formatted table in the message. And unless you are using a third-party API to manipulate Notes rich text, you are going to have to build your email as a MIME/HTML message instead of an ordinary Notes rich text message. Below is an illustration of the basic coding that you will need to start creating a MIME message with HTML content.

```
Session.convertMIME = False 
Dim body As NotesMIMEEntity
Dim hdr As NotesMIMEHeader
Dim entity As NotesMIMEEntity
Set body = mailDoc.CreateMIMEEntity
Set hdr = body.CreateHeader({MIME-Version})
Call hdr.SetHeaderVal("1.0")
Set hdr = body.CreateHeader("Content-Type")
Call hdr.SetHeaderValAndParams({text/html"})
Call body.SetContentFromText( { The HTML That You Built From Excel Data Goes Here } )
```

Comment: Thank you Richard for your reply, I did see this method referenced in one of the previous threads and in other places around the internet, and I tried to make sense of this but I was just not able to understand.. I guess my level of understanding is just not there yet.. I will keep trying but that said, I know it's a lot to ask but if you could put something together for me so I can send the referenced range as a MIME\HTML message, I promise I will buy you a beer sometime!

Comment: I have updated my answer to show the basics of starting to form a MME message and send it via the Notes API. @flykarthick suggested using NotesRichTextTable instead, and this might be easier than reverting to MIME, but I haven't looked at the NotesRichText classes in a while and don't recall how much control they give you over table formatting.

Comment: Thank you Richard! but how do I make a reference to a certain range in my worksheet in order to build the HTML? can you give an example with the range I refered to in my code?

Comment: I don't know the Excel API calls for doing that. I don't even know if Excel provides an API for generating HTML. You may have to read it cell by cell and build it yourself. I'm not sure.

Comment: I very much appreciate you taking the time to reply, thanks again!

Comment: You are welcome. Upvoting my answer is a good way to show your appreciation.